# Locate the sibling element of self or perent node in xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find an element which can be preceding sibling of self node or its parent's node .

I have to get all textfield values along with the label present for them as given this image :

[image]

If I see the DOM I found following structure as mentioned in snap

[image]

I have tried below code

```
 // this is the xpath to get all the textboxes

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[not(@id='fuPanCardFilePath')][not(@type='hidden')][not(@id='fuIDProofFilePath' or @id='txtChangePhone' or @id='txtOTP' )]")
public List<WebElement> allTextFieldsDetails;


// This how i am getting labels of correspondent textfield

for(WebElement e : allTextFieldsDetails)
{
    LogWriter.logger.info(e.findElement(By.xpath("preceding-sibling::label")).getText() +"---"+e.getAttribute("value"));
}
```

Its working fine for those `<label>` which is exact preceding-sibling of `<input>` but if a `label` is preceding-sibling of the parent `div` of a `input` tag then its throw the exception `NoSuchElementException`.

This is HTML structure :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <label>Last Name </label>
        <input id="LastName" class="form-control valid" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Last Name must be a string with a maximum length of 20." data-val-length-max="20" data-val-regex="Please enter valid Last Name" data-val-regex-pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" data-val-required="Please enter valid Last Name" maxlength="20" name="LastName" placeholder="Last Name" value="Kapadia" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="LastName-error" aria-invalid="false" type="text"/>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LastName" data-valmsg-replace="true"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <label>Email ID</label>
        <input id="Email" class="form-control valid" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Email must be a string with a maximum length of 320." data-val-length-max="320" data-val-regex="Please enter valid Email" data-val-regex-pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$" data-val-required="Please enter valid Email" maxlength="80" name="Email" placeholder="Email" value="narendra.h.rajput@trimantra.net" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="Email-error" aria-invalid="false" type="email"/>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <label>Date Of Birth</label>
        <div class="input-append date tspDOB-date">
            <input id="DOB" class="form-control" value="1989-09-09" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date of Birth must be a date." data-val-required="Please enter a valid birth date" name="DOB" placeholder="Date of Birth" type="text"/>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DOB" data-valmsg-replace="true"/>
            <span class="add-on"/>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <label>Mobile No</label>
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group displayinlinediv">
            <input id="Mobile" class="form-control valid" name="Mobile" readonly="readonly" value="00000000000" aria-invalid="false" type="text"/>
            <button id="btnchange" class="btn btn-common-left" type="button">Change</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to locate the labels correspondent to input fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
preceding::label[1]
```

to get the first `label` element which can be sibling or sibling of parent or grand-parent...

Also note that you can simplify `XPath` for `input` elements as

```
//input[not(@type='hidden') and not(@id=('fuIDProofFilePath', 'txtChangePhone', 'txtOTP', 'fuPanCardFilePath'))]
```

Comment: @Thanks Andersson, the this  one `preceding::label[1]` is working fine for me . but  the simplified  string is not showing valid in firepath.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(.|..)/preceding-sibling::label='xyz'`.

Note that if you mean the *immediately* preceding sibling then it should be `preceding-sibling::label[1]`